# Is there a way to see what modes I've cleared?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

There are challenges such as:

- Clear classic with all fighters
- Win smash run with all fighters
- Clear solo 100-man smash with all fighters
- Clear all-star with 15 fighters

My question is, how do I know if I've completed it or not? It seems that even if I fail, I get a score assigned, so there seems to be no simple indicator of whether or not I've completed a particular game mode with any given fighter.

Comment: Not sure about the others but classic gives you that fighters trophy when you clear it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ways to check what characters cleared what are as follows:

- For classic, check for the fighter's trophies and for all-star check for their alt trophies. One thing to note about all-star is if you clear it with two players you will get the other player's fighter's alt trophy, but you won't get the clear for it. If you are playing alone you don't have to worry about it.
- In solo 100-man smash, just check the score. If it is a time you cleared it. If it is just a number from 0-99 it means you have not cleared it yet.
- For smash run, go to Vault -> Records -> Fight Records -> Smash Run -> Victories. Anyone with 0 wins did not place first in it yet.

Comment: A bit tedious, but sufficient nonetheless. Thank you.